Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information
An error in the title was output in an application running on Google Kubernetes Engine.
Specifically, an error occurs because the application does not have permission to access Cloud Storage.
Furthermore, at the time this event occurred, we were releasing an application that added a new Pub/Sub topic, and at the same time we were also registering the scheduler for the topic using terraform.
The questions are as follows.
・Please tell me the log message that shows that the default credentials are incorrect.
・Please tell me the log message that shows that default credentials have been set.
After the error occurred, this error was resolved by deploying the same module again.

Kubernetes Pods logging to stdout and stderr will be ingested by Cloud Logging and available as log_id("stderr") (or logName="projects/{your-project-id}/logs/stderr") where they can be queried by the API, gcloud logging read or https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query. One way to filter log entries is to query with the error message e.g. Could not load the default credentials and refine the query as needed.

Credential use should be available in the Audit Logs (log_id("cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity")) and you can filter by protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail for example.

It's curious that you're receiving this error. Unless you're explicitly referencing the credentials (which is an anti-pattern), I'm unsure when this error would arise. It may be worthwhile to review the code that's generating this error.
